# Why does handedness matter at all?

Tags: 3d, vector, coordinates

I'm really trying to understand this from a mathematical viewpoint. After all, numbers are numbers, the chirality or handedness depends on how one interprets it.

Say I've three basis vectors **x** (1, 0, 0), **y** (0, 1, 0) and **z** (0, 0, 1). The same basis vectors would be seen differently by the two systems *but* the numbers remain the same.

[image]

When we do a cross product of **x** and **y** we'd get **z** in both systems, again the numbers of the result are the same, it's just the interpretation of the observer.

Then why do I see questions about handedness all the time? Is there a place where a game developer needs to differentiate and work in converting between the two really? Eric Haines in a [related article](http://www.realtimerendering.com/blog/left-handed-vs-right-handed-viewing/) uses the term "right-handed data". What does this really mean, aren't they all numbers? Why would they force a coordinate system on the user? Also do APIs like GL or DX force a system at some point? I've read somewhere that, in OpenGL the camera is always at origin looking at -Z direction, while it's the opposite in DirectX.

It'd be great if someone can list out where this convention really makes a difference and why.

**EDIT:** I think can explain it more explicitly since many seem to misunderstand the question (sorry, I'm not a native speaker of this tongue). Why do people talk about converting an asset for handedness? Say a triangle with coords (0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0) and (1, 0, 0) would mean the same in both systems mathematically, where is the handedness here?

Comment: Preference really. People in Science just don't like to be limited to one possibility when there are more. If there is another possibility, why not? As long you keep your conventions clear and consistent. Both systems give you the same result. As long the translations are converted correctly.

Comment: @Sidar: Please see the edit added to the question. I think the question was misunderstood, I know that 2 (or more) such conventions exist, and I'm fine by them, I'll keep them consistent in my world/system/code, but why/when would I come across converting, even if I'm consistent?

Comment: Again the person picking either handedness probably just picked it because it seemed more intuitive ( or whatever excuse he had ). You hardly convert between coordinate systems unless you use a combination of frameworks/engines that don't use the same handedness. But you can also assume that most frameworks come with a function to flatten a transformation matrix. Which allows you to easily put one transformation matrix into another coordinate system. Mind you I could be wrong on this. Someone should confirm this ( the reason it's a comment and not an answer )

Comment: @Sidar: Aah, got it! See the matrix put in an asset depends on the handedness assumed by the designer which forces a handedness on a dev, now that's something tangible and clearly understandable! List of such things is what is wanted in the answer :)

Comment: http://www.mindcontrol.org/~hplus/graphics/matrix-layout.html Here is some info on the two. Apparently it's a case of transposing the matrix in this case for OpenGl and DirectX. So it looks like you don't really need to convert much.

Comment: Yes, but like the author of the page says, the math is the same, matrix is the same, it's differs on the interpretation. I wonder how he says it's the same, since using the same matrix for both would lead to incorrect results, one should be transposed before using with the other, which means it isn't the same anymore.

Comment: It simply has to do with the fact how you read the elements, in what order. I think that's what he meant with interpretation. But I haven't done much with this. So I guess It's best a person in this field points you in the right direction.

Comment: Btw, you just described a triangle. The points are defined but It says nothing about the handedness. Absolutely nothing. Keep in mind you can't change the orientation of the left handed coordinates to make it fit into the right handed coordinate system. The handedness only becomes visible when it's explicitly specified. Right handed is actually rotated to make the x+ axis to point to the right. In it's default orientation it points to the left( something we aren't used to ). Also the reason the Z+ axis point in opposite ways.

Comment: I think you still got me wrong, there's no such thing called "left (or right) handed coordinates" that's precisely my point. Those are just points, which can be interpreted in a left or right handed system, so why is there a differentiation. The axes pointing in different direction and all that is the interpretation of the observer.

Comment: Yes there is. There is a left and right handed coordinate system. I explicitly told you why. You cannot change the orientation of the left handed system to make it fit into the right handed system ( nor can you do it the other way around obviously). It's impossible. Go ahead try it. (hint: You won't succeed ). You are confused by the idea that there is no difference between the alignment of the axis in the positive directing. And there certainly is. Because you can't twist/turn/rotate the coordinate space to align with the other. No matter how hard you try.

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @TrevorPowell: I'm learning CG. Specifically now I'm trying to understand about handedness and when they're really a problem. Say if, I, as a developer always interpret/see all data in RHS, then when would I be bitten by it and why is precisely my question? Reason is, the numbers seem to not force any handedness on me, it's just how people interpret it.

Comment: @TrevorPowell: It all started with a line in the CG math book I'm reading which goes, "Formally, if we have three vectors {v0, v1, v2}, then they are right-handed, if v0 · (v1 x v2) > 0, and left-handed if v0 · (v1 x v2) < 0." Now, when I think of the basis vectors X, Y, Z, in both LHS and RHS X x Y = Z, then how would the above line hold true?

Comment: @Sidar Thanks for patiently trying to make me understand :) I've finally understood it, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure about OpenGL but DirectX allows you to over write the default left-handedness therefore it wouldn't matter. As you've said, it's "nothing but" a convention, and at least DirectX allows you to work with both. Conventions do not matter by themselves, the only problem is that you need to be consistent with your choice. Mixing two such systems leads to either confusion (if you do make the conversions) or to all sorts of errors if you do not (but why would anyone do that, except for mistakes).

As to what Eric Haines refers to as "right-handed data" I bring this quote from the beginning "OK, so only for viewing you must also know the handedness of the data." and that's exactly where handedness matters, when viewing it. Does a Z-component of 1 make the object closest possible to the screen or furthest? That's why you need to know the handedness of the data, to interpret the data correctly when doing the depth test.

Comment: OpenGL allows it too. http://seanmiddleditch.com/journal/2012/08/matrices-handedness-pre-and-post-multiplication-row-vs-column-major-and-notations/

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm starting to see it. So when I've a unit cube where the face opposite to XY plane where z = 1 is the face of a model (as per the artist who prefers LHS), if I just use the points in a RHS viewing system (without taking into account the handedness) then my cube will be behind my camera with its face on the other side, since my camera is pointing to z = -1. If I want to animate a zoom in to the face, on a LHS viewing system I can just increase camera's z, while in RHS, I've to do something round about.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter in the sense that the handedness is arbitrary; either way works fine so they just picked one. They only "force" their way on the user in the sense that they had to pick something so they went with that way.

However it *does* matter in that you need to be consistent about what the numbers mean; it doesn't matter what decision was made initially, but once a decision is made you need to stick with it. For example, when you say:

> When we do a cross product of x and y we'd get z in both systems, again the numbers of the result are the same, it's just the interpretation of the observer.

that's not exactly true. The magnitude of the resulting vector is the same, but they point in opposite directions.

Comment: "but they point in opposite directions" - only because you're viewing both the vectors (of 2 different spaces) in a 3rd common reference space do they point in opposite direction; in their space, they point in the same direction, which is +Z direction.

Comment: Well yeah, but... here let me try a different approach. Think about your own body and the word "left". The word "left" refers to one side of your body, but couldn't it just as easily refer to the other side? Why does it matter? The answer to those questions is the answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

Handedness — and choice of axes, in the same way — matter because *the camera has to match* to get the results you want.

Suppose that you had a dataset (scene) which included not only the objects to view, but also a definition of the camera, in terms of a position and (right, up, forward) basis vectors and a winding order for face culling. In that case, then obviously once you apply the camera transformation to the data you get the same screen-space points no matter how the data is arranged in world space.

The reason that we care about the axes/handedness/ordering of 3D data is because in games, **the camera is not defined in the data** but added by the game engine afterward, so we choose a camera design and say that all the data has to match that. (Also, multiple 3D models are combined in one scene, and they *all* have to match the camera, or be transformed to match.)